# UnityContainer resolve all types for one interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(IBar[] bars);
}
```

IBar has multiple implementations that are all registered in the UnityContainer.
When I call

```
UnityContainer.Resolve()
```

I want that the container to inject all known IBar implementations into the object.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as your registered types have a **name applied to them**:

```
container.RegisterType<IBar, ActualBar>("ActualBar");
container.RegsiterType<IBar, YetAnotherBar>("YetAnotherBar");
```

And given a proper public constructor as you mention:

```
public Foo(IBar[] bars)
{
}
```

Unity will take care of resolving all named registered instances into your constructor out of the box.

```
Foo foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
```

Comment: Why does it need a name? I mean i expect it to work even without a name!

Comment: As long as each name is unique you will see all your instances or have access to them